# Flutter firebase messaging v9.0.0 - Not firing events

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that was using firebase messaging 7.0.3 and all worked perfectly. But when I migrated to firebase messaging 9.0.0, the push notifications are not being handled.

I know that the app is correctly linked to firebase and cloud messaging because in background I see the push notification comming, the problem is when I click that notification the app don't handle this event. Also, when the app is in foreground, the event of receiving the notification is not being triggered.

Specifically, the functions FirebaseMessaging.onMessage and FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp are not working. My code is:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("notification: message");
}); 
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("notification: resume");
});
```

The prints are never called, and if I put some more code inside isn't executed too.

I also call FirebaseMessaging.getToken and I can get the token, plus when the app is in background I get the push notification, so is not a link problem with firebase. In the logs, when I receive the push I can see a message saying: Broadcast received for message. So I assumed that the push is arriving in all the occasions, and I am doing something wrong in the code.

I tested all cases in Android and iOS physical devices.

Someone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this exact same issue after migrating and upgrading to 9.0.0.

There is a minor issue with 9.0.0 plugin.
The fix can be found here:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4949

To cut a long story short, if you navigate to the definition of the factory
`RemoteMessage.fromMap()` Using **Cmd+Click** or **Ctrl+Click** while hovering over the RemoteMessage class with the mouse), in the return statement, change `contentAvailable: map['contentAvailable']`, to `contentAvailable: map['contentAvailable']??false`.

Notifications are now working for me again now.
This should work for you until the plugin is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I already tried that and still doesn't work. I checked the field in case it's null to be false and I also tried to assign always false, but this not fixed my issue.

Comment: @Santi the change mentioned in the answer should be added in the `remote_message.dart` file (cached), until you get the next update for the sdk

Comment: I have the same problem, but this fix also did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Was able to get it working by **also** changing `mutableContent: map['mutableContent'],` to `mutableContent: map['mutableContent']??false,`

Comment: Changing both contentAvailable and mutableContent solves the issue. Thank you to all!

Comment: i'm using firebase plugin version 9.0.2 with the same problem, i get notifications in fore and background, but i was unable to manage the ontap notification action.
this already fix the ??false changes but the function:
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    });
does not work

Comment: hey i am using firebase_messaging: ^9.1.3 plugin and this is resolved bugs.  but 

 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    });

but onTap on Push notification is not working please help!!

Comment: same here, using the messaging 10.0.0 version which already has the mutableContent and available content fixed in the source code.

Comment: I am using the latest FCM package but FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen never triggered after clicking the notification .  this `contentAvailable: map['contentAvailable']??false` already there

Comment: Same issue on ^11.2.0